# How I can set environment parameter to nodejs with EXPORT?

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

I have .npmrc with value for scope registry

```
@myScope:registry="myHtml"
```

I delete the .npmrc and I want to do it with npm config

I tried `export npm_config_@myScope:registry=myHtml` and the I got  **not a valid identifier**

I tried 
 export VARNAME="npm_config_@myScope:registry"
 export VARNAME=myHtml" but it didn't update the environment parameter

Answer (score 0):

You should use Node's Process object for that.

```
process.env.VARNAME = "myHTML"
```

This should expose your variable through you project.
You can find more about it here: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env

Comment: I saw that this is working  npm config set @myscope:registry 
is it possible to do the same with export ?

Comment: Cannot reach the site that you have given me here... :(

Comment: I want to do it from terminal so how I can set env in npm with __config ?

Comment: and I prefer to do it in one line like export npm_config_@myScope:registry=myHtml